# Efficiently get minimum values for each pair of elements from two arrays in a third array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have two arrays of `N` floats (which act as `(x,y)` coordinates and might have duplicates) and and associated `z` array of `N` floats (which act as weights for the coordinates).

For each `(x,y)` pair of floats I need to select the pair with the smallest associated `z` value. I've defined a `selectMinz()` function which does this (see code below) but it takes too long.

How could I improve the performance of this function?

```
import numpy as np
import time


def getData():
    N = 100000
    x = np.arange(0.0005, 0.03, 0.001)
    y = np.arange(6., 10., .05)
    # Select N values for x,y, where values can be repeated
    x = np.random.choice(x, N)
    y = np.random.choice(y, N)
    z = np.random.uniform(10., 15., N)
    return x, y, z


def selectMinz(x, y, z):
    """
    Select the minimum z for each (x,y) pair.
    """
    xy_unq, z_unq = [], []
    # For each (x,y) pair
    for i, xy in enumerate(zip(*[x, y])):
        # If this xy pair was already stored in the xy_unq list
        if xy in xy_unq:
            # If the stored z value associated with this xy pair is
            # larger than this new z[i] value
            if z_unq[xy_unq.index(xy)] > z[i]:
                # Store this smaller value instead
                z_unq[xy_unq.index(xy)] = z[i]
        else:
            # Store the xy pair, and its associated z value
            xy_unq.append(xy)
            z_unq.append(z[i])

    return xy_unq, z_unq


# Define data with the proper format.
x, y, z = getData()

s = time.clock()
xy_unq, z_unq = selectMinz(x, y, z)  # <-- TAKES TOO LONG (~15s in my system)
print(time.clock() - s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Steps :**

1. Use `lex-sort` to make the `x-y` pairs come in sequence. Or, we can use a scaling method to scale one of the arrays by the range of values on the other and then sum it with the other array and finally use `argsort` to get the lex-sorted equivalent indices.
2. Use `np.minimum.reduceat` to get the minimum values in intervals, defined by the pair groupings.

Thus, we would have one vectorized solution, like so -

```
def selectMinz_vectorized(x, y, z):
    # Get grouped lex-sort indices
    sidx = (y + x*(y.max() - y.min() + 1)).argsort()
    # or sidx = np.lexsort([x, y])

    # Lex-sort x, y, z
    x_sorted = x[sidx]
    y_sorted = y[sidx]
    z_sorted = z[sidx]

    # Get equality mask between each sorted X and Y elem against previous ones.
    # The non-zero indices of its inverted mask gives us the indices where the 
    # new groupings start. We are calling those as cut_idx.
    seq_eq_mask = (x_sorted[1:] == x_sorted[:-1]) & (y_sorted[1:] == y_sorted[:-1])
    cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(( [True], ~seq_eq_mask)))

    # Use those cut_idx to get intervalled minimum values
    minZ = np.minimum.reduceat(z_sorted, cut_idx)

    # Make tuples of the groupings of x,y and the corresponding min Z values
    return (zip(x_sorted[cut_idx], y_sorted[cut_idx]), minZ.tolist())
```

Sample run -

```
In [120]: np.c_[x,y,z]
Out[120]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,  69.],
       [  2.,   0.,  47.],
       [  1.,   0.,  62.],
       [  0.,   2.,  33.],
       [  1.,   7.,  32.],
       [  1.,   0.,  50.],
       [  2.,   0.,  55.]])

In [121]: selectMinz(x,y,z) # original method
Out[121]: 
([(0.0, 1.0), (2.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0), (1.0, 7.0)],
 [69.0, 47.0, 50.0, 33.0, 32.0])

In [122]: selectMinz_vectorized(x,y,z)
Out[122]: 
([(1.0, 0.0), (2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 2.0), (1.0, 7.0)],
 [50.0, 47.0, 69.0, 33.0, 32.0])
```

---

Here's my initial approach that involved creating a stacked array and then perform those operations. The implementation looked something like this -

```
def selectMinz_vectorized_v2(x, y, z):
    d = np.column_stack((x,y,z))
    sidx = np.lexsort(d[:,:2].T)
    b = d[sidx]  
    cut_idx = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(~(b[1:,:2] == b[:-1,:2]).all(1))+1]
    minZ = np.minimum.reduceat(b[:,-1], cut_idx)
    return ([tuple(i) for i in b[cut_idx,:2]], minZ.tolist())
```

---

**Benchmarking for the vectorized approaches**

Approaches -

```
# Pruned version of the approach posted earlier
def selectMinz_vectorized_pruned(x, y, z):
    sidx = (y + x*(y.max() - y.min() + 1)).argsort()
    x_sorted = x[sidx]
    y_sorted = y[sidx]
    z_sorted = z[sidx]
    seq_eq_mask = (x_sorted[1:] == x_sorted[:-1]) & (y_sorted[1:] == y_sorted[:-1])
    cut_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(( [True], ~seq_eq_mask)))
    minZ = np.minimum.reduceat(z_sorted, cut_idx)
    return x_sorted[cut_idx], y_sorted[cut_idx], minZ

def numpy_indexed_app(x,y,z): # @Eelco Hoogendoorn's soln
    return npi.group_by((x, y)).min(z)
```

Timings -

```
In [141]: x,y,z=getData(10000)

In [142]: %timeit selectMinz_vectorized_pruned(x, y, z)
     ...: %timeit numpy_indexed_app(x,y,z)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 763 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop

In [143]: x,y,z=getData(100000)

In [144]: %timeit selectMinz_vectorized_pruned(x, y, z)
     ...: %timeit numpy_indexed_app(x,y,z)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.53 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: I knew there'd be a vectorized way :) That syntax is unwieldy though and my timings are `10 loops, best of 3: 79.4 ms per loop` for the dict method and `10 loops, best of 3: 25.6 ms per loop` for this. I wonder if there's any hope in Pandas competing here? Is this the kind of thing that it's translating syntactically clean functions to?

Comment: I'm not sure how to unpack the data returned by your function. Could you make it return the data in the same format as the original function please?

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Although this function is (to me) 100 times harder to read than the one by Antimony, it also is more than 2X faster. Hence, I'm selecting it. Thanks again!

Comment: A personal question sorry :( . From which resources you learned to apply these vectorized solution .

Comment: @roganjosh On performance, I guess it could have been the concatenation. Edited with one method that avoids it. Could you please check out the performance again if you still have that setup?

Comment: @Divakar I deleted my previous comment btw where I questioned if this gave correct answer, I was incorrect in the sorting of my output to yours. Currently I'm on `1 loop, best of 3: 116 ms per loop` for Pandas btw. I will retest your code after the edit now.

Comment: `100 loops, best of 3: 19.8 ms per loop` now so it seems there's some improvement with your edit :). This has been a nice exercise for learning more about numpy and pandas, thanks, and your new code is _so_ much more intelligible to me than the first post.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks alot for getting back with those numbers! It's a good feeling to see some improvement there!

Comment: I can confirm this new function is almost 2X faster than the old one, and MUCH more readable. Excellent work!

Comment: @NimishBansal Just through answering MATLAB/NumPy questions on here and avoiding loops the most religious way possible ;)

Answer (score 3):

Changing the data structure of `xy_unq` and `z_unq` to a dictionary that holds both pieces of information brought the time down from ~7s to ~0.1s on my system.

```
def selectMinz(x, y, z):
    """
    Select the minimum z for each (x,y) pair.
    """
    xy_unq = {}
    # For each (x,y) pair
    for i, xy in enumerate(zip(*[x, y])):
        # If this xy pair was already stored in the xy_unq list
        if xy in xy_unq:
            # If the stored z value associated with this xy pair is
            # larger than this new z[i] value
            if xy_unq[xy] > z[i]:
                # Store this smaller value instead
                xy_unq[xy] = z[i]
        else:
            # Store the xy pair, and its associated z value
            xy_unq[xy] = z[i]

    return xy_unq.keys(), xy_unq.values()
```

The time for the above approach for me ranged from ~0.106s to ~0.11s. Here is an alternative approach with fewer lines of code, but takes slightly more time (~0.14):

```
def selectMinz(x, y, z):
    """
    Select the minimum z for each (x,y) pair.
    """
    xy_unq = {}
    # For each (x,y) pair
    for i, xy in enumerate(zip(*[x, y])):
        # If this xy pair was already stored in the xy_unq list
        if xy in xy_unq:
            # Store the value that is smaller between the current stored value and the new z[i]
            xy_unq[xy] = min(xy_unq[xy], z[i])
        else:
            # Store the xy pair, and its associated z value
            xy_unq[xy] = z[i]

    return xy_unq.keys(), xy_unq.values()
```

Comment: You are storing the `z` values in `xy_unq`, this is not correct.

Comment: I am storing `xy` as a key and its associated minimum `z` as the value. If you need the final list of all the `z`'s, you can easily get them by calling `xy_unq.values()`.

Comment: Yes, I need both the `xy_unq` list and the `z_unq` list. Add a line to return them in the correct format, if it is still faster than mine I'll accept it.

Comment: @Gabriel I have a feeling that there's a vectorized approach for this, I just don't know it (and would like to).... This approach is perfectly fine (upvoted) but it defeats the point of numpy in the first place. I would suggest you leave the question open for now.

Comment: @Gabriel There ya go!

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and much more readable than the one by Divakar. Since I need the one with the best performance possible, I selected the other answer, but thank you very much for yours!

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains functionality to solve these kind of grouping problems in an elegant and efficient manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
xy_unq, z_unq = npi.group_by((x, y)).min(z)
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution! Have you timed it against the code by Divakar?

Comment: @Gabriel Added in my post.

Comment: This is nice. Is there a reason this can't be part of numpy? From the timings given by @Divakar it's surely in the ballpark for competing with a custom approach and the syntax is similar to Pandas

Comment: Thanks. The steps taken below the hood are conceptually identical to those of Divakar; but with a little overhead here and there to facilitate generality. I wrote this initially as a suggestion for improvement to numpy; but working on it more i felt that the subtle backwards compatibility requirements numpy imposes were too restrictive; and that I kinda like the ability to iterate on this set of functionality quickly, rather than be restricted to their release cycle.

Comment: That said, the more numpy manages to backport from this package, the better. One step in the right direction is the new numpy support for having an axis kwarg in np.unique, so you can find unique rows and so on without having to hack that in yourself. But I feel that a solid group-by definitely should be within the scope of numpy; such data-wrangling is much more at the core of what numpy should be about than say, ffts. OTOH, package management is  so good nowadays that it arguably makes more sense to split up numpy into more micropackages; something like this being one of them.